# override searchBox of material-table

Tags: reactjs, material-table

```
import SearchBar from "material-ui-search-bar";
    
function TableofUser() {   
     const [searched, setSearched] = useState();
        const [Company, setCompany] = useState([
            {
              id: "1",
              name: "شاهین رضوانی",
              email: "shahin@gmail.com",
              Beehive: "زنبورستان 1",
              Role: "نقش",
            },
            {
              id: "2",
              name: "شاهین کاظمی",
              email: "shahin@gmail.com",
              Beehive: "زنبورستان 3",
              Role: "نقش",
            },
          ]);
                          function TableofUser() {  
                              const requestSearch = (searchedVal) => {
                                console.log("searchedVal", searchedVal);
                                const filteredRows = Company.map((rows) => {
                                  return rows;
                                }).filter((row) => {
                                  console.log("row", row.name);
                                  return row.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchedVal.toLowerCase());
                                });
                                setCompany(filteredRows);
                                console.log("Company", Company);
                                console.log("filteredRows", filteredRows);
                              };
                         return (
                            <div>
                <MaterialTable
                     components={{
                              Toolbar: (props) => (
                                <>
                                  <div
                                    style={{
                                      direction: "rtl",
                                      display: "flex",
                                      justifyContent: "space-between",
                                      alignItems: "center",
                                      padding: "16px  32px  0px",
                                    }}
                                  >
                                    <div
                                      style={{
                                        display: "flex",
                                        alignItems: "center",
                                        justifyContent: "center",
                                      }}
                                    >
                                      <SearchBar
                                        style={{
                                          direction: "ltr",
                                          border: "1px solid red",
                                          width: "100%",
                                          borderRadius: "8px",
                                        }}
                                        value={searched}
                                        onChange={(searchVal) => requestSearch(searchVal)}
                                        // onCancelSearch={() => cancelSearch()}
                                      />
                                      {/* <MTableToolbar {...props} /> */}
                                      <div
                                        onClick={handleOpen}
                                        style={{
                                          backgroundColor: "rgb( 227, 156, 0)",
                                          marginRight: "32px",
                                          color: "#000",
                                          padding: "8px",
                                          display: "flex",
                                          alignItems: "center",
                                          justifyContent: "center",
                                          borderRadius: "8px",
                                        }}
                                      >
                                        <img src="/assets/Group 182.svg" />
                                      </div>
                    
                                      <FormControl
                                        sx={{ m: 1, minWidth: 120 }}
                                        className={classes.inputSelect}
                                      >
                                        {/* <InputLabel htmlFor="grouped-native-select">Grouping</InputLabel> */}
                    
                                        <Select
                                          className={classes.inputSelect}
                                          variant="outlined"
                                          native
                                          onChange={handleSelectChange}
                                          id="VegetationOfTheArea"
                                          name="VegetationOfTheArea"
                                        >
                                          <option aria-label="VegetationOfTheArea" value="" />
                                          <optgroup label="Category 1">
                                            <option value={1}>Optijjjkjon 1</option>
                                            <option value={2}>fgffghnion 2</option>
                                          </optgroup>
                                          <optgroup label="Category 2">
                                            <option value={3}>jhjjjhhg</option>
                                            <option value={4}>;;;jk</option>
                                          </optgroup>
                                        </Select>
                                      </FormControl>
                                    </div>
                                    <div
                                      onClick={downloadFile}
                                      style={{
                                        backgroundColor: "black",
                                        cursor: "pointer",
                                        color: "white",
                                        display: "flex",
                                        alignItems: "center",
                                        justifyContent: "center",
                                        borderRadius: "8px",
                                        padding: "8px",
                                        // marginLeft: "32px",
                                      }}
                                    >
                                      <span>دانلود</span>
                                      <img
                                        src="/assets/download-arrow-svgrepo-com.svg"
                                        style={{ marginRight: "8px" }}
                                      />
                                    </div>
                                  </div>
                                  <hr
                                    style={{
                                      borderTop: "1px solid rgb( 240, 240, 240)",
                                      height: "2px",
                                    }}
                                  />
                                  {toolbar ? (
                                    <MTableToolbar {...props}>{console.log(props)}</MTableToolbar>
                                  ) : null}
                                </>
                              ),
                            }}
                    />
                       </div>
                                );}
            export default TableofUser;
        
    
 I want to override the search table of the material table. I implemented the SearchBar component according to the following code, in which I defined the requestSearch function for the onchange property.
    In the requestSearch function, I defined the filteredRows constant, and using it the filter method and the includes method,
             

          

 function TableofUser() {  
                          const requestSearch = (searchedVal) => {
                            console.log("searchedVal", searchedVal);
                     `enter code here`       const filteredRows = Company.map((rows) => {
                              return rows;
                            }).filter((row) => {
                              console.log("row", row.name);
                              return row.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchedVal.toLowerCase());
                            });
                            setCompany(filteredRows);
                            console.log("Company", Company);
                            console.log("filteredRows", filteredRows);
                          };
```

I want to update and filter the material-table according to the search words in the SearchBar section, but I get an error when searching.
Although the constant filteredRows is displayed correctly on the console and works correctly ,but I have a problem when I update the State Company
Thanks if anyone can help me fix this error

```
<SearchBar
                  style={{
                     direction: "ltr",
                     border: "1px solid red",
                     width: "100%",
                     borderRadius: "8px",
                                        }}
                     value={searched}
                     onChange={(searchVal) => requestSearch(searchVal)}
         
                                      />
```